# Motivation behind word quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

Why set of all cosets of a subspace W of a vector space V is called quotient space. What is the motivation behind word quotient?

Comment: Because you have *divided* your whole set into pieces. If you divide a 500g cake into 125g portions, you'll get a quotient set of 4 pieces, 4 = 500/125.

Answer (score 5):

Because the quotient of $V \times W$ by $W$ is $V$.

(more precisely, the quotient of $V \times W$ by the subspace $\{ 0 \} \times W$ is naturally isomorphic to $V$)

There are more general situations, but that it covers this particular situation is, in my opinion, a pretty strong motivation.

The idea is even clearer in the case of abelian groups; finite abelian groups are sort of like numbers. If $C_k$ denotes a cyclic group of $k$ elements, then the quotient of $C_{mn}$ by the subgroup (isomorphic to) $C_m$ is (isomorphic to) $C_n$.

---

The notion of quotient can even be applied to pure sets; if $\sim$ is an *equivalence relation* on a set $S$, then there is a quotient set $S/\!\!\sim$; typically we define this to be the set of equivalence classes.

If every equivalence class has exactly $m$ elements, then $|S /\!\!\sim\!\!| = \frac{|S|}{m}$

Answer (score 1):

Two possible motivations:

For finite-dimensional vector spaces over finite fields,

$$
|V/W|=|V|/|W|\;.
$$

And for $m\mid n$,

$$
n\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\sim(n/m)\mathbb Z\;.
$$

More generally, see also the Wikipedia article on [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class). Whenever the equivalence classes of an equivalence relation all have the same size $d$, forming the quotient with respect to that equivalence relation divides the size of the structure by $d$.